# How to set a custom Profile URL for my user?

Tags: php

you all know that if you login to your Facebook or Twitter account, you see a URL on address bar like this: https://web.facebook.com/iamakm15. That means your username appears on URL. My question is, how Facebook and Twitter did this? I mean what programming language did they use to show the username in the URL?

Now, when I login to my profile, I get a URL like this: http://localhost/AKM.PHP/project_akm/profile.php, so how can I add username after profile.php like this: /profile.php/imakm15 to my URL?

Comment: You probably want to look into .htaccess url rewriting. All URLs are routet to a script (profile.php in your case) where its decided what to display (profile page if the user exists, 404 page otherwise).

Comment: Please do not tag every framework you can think of - just the one that you are intending to use.

Comment: @Connum This is what I've found in .htaccess. I have no idea what to do here: AuthType Basic
AuthName "FORBIDDEN AREA"
AuthUserfile "../htdocs/forbidden/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user

Comment: look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine and here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: if u really want to do like : /profile.php/imakm15, replace "/" with "?" and easily done ! but if you really want something like fb or ... use : RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?profile=$1 [NC,L,QSA] and in your profile.php use $_GET["profile"]

Comment: Hey @Soheyl,  "if u really want to do like : /profile.php/imakm15, replace "/" with "?" and easily done!" I didn't get this part. I mean where to go and replace this thing?

Comment: @AKM Just add ?imakm15 add the end of ur URL : http://localhost/AKM.PHP/project_akm/profile.php => http://localhost/AKM.PHP/project_akm/profile.php?imakm15

Comment: Guys, I'm a beginner. Maybe That's why I didn't understand a word. But thank you guys for commenting and trying to help. It's my bad I didn't get u ppl.

Answer (score 1):

Later later edit ( didn't have space for full explanation in comment)

Ok, good. Let's start with the beginning. When you don't have rewrite setup on yoru server, your link will look like this:

http://localhost/AKM.PHP/project_akm/profile.php?username=iamakm15

Profile.php will extract the parameter with $_GET['username'] in your php code, it will make a query in database, where clause username='iamakm15' and it will extract the info associated with 'iamakm15'.  If this step is already done and it works, in your root localhost ( you need to place this file at this level:localhost in order to work), add a file called '.htaccess' - if you already have one, just add these lines:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^AKM.PHP/Project_akm/([^/\.]+)/?$ /AKM.PHP/Project_akm/profile.php?username=$1  [L]
```

After saving this file, just try to access url:
http://localhost/AKM.PM/project_akm/iamakm15

and you should see the page with info about user: iamakm15. Make this exercise with different usernames from database, by modifying iamakm15 with other one.

if you get a 500 error you can add a new rule ( after RewriteBase / ):

```
RewriteRule ^/AKM.PHP/Project_akm/profile\.php$ - [L]
```

because can match itself after redirect.

Comment: Hey Vas, I found a file called (dot) .htaccess. but could not find httaccess. and where to write those code? can u pls explain a lil bit? thanks

Comment: Hi AKM, that is the file you need: ".htaccess"; sorry I forgot to mention full name.  In your case, just add this file in http://localhost/AKM.PHP/project_akm/ and write : RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L] and when you will use: http://localhost/AKM.PM/project_akm/johndoe , basically parameter username, in this case johndoe will be passed to profile.php

Comment: Hey Vas, please see my last comment above your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Vas, I have watched a video and read some article about URL rewriting. but it's not working. hey, can i have your email pls?

Comment: Vas , this is my email: imakm15@gmail.com. pls send me an email bro. thanks